# Test PHP Files when connecting Android to server

Tags: java, php, android, intellij-idea

I am trying to make an Android app connect to a database. Currently, I do not have a web host that holds the database, therefore I am using Wamp to test my files first. I decided to use Intellij Idea to create the Android app, and I think I have connected the database window to my Wamp database (this is the URL that Intellij shows: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/stickyrice). With this in mind, I have tried doing initial research and find ways to connect Android apps to a database. However, my question is how I could test my PHP files that they have connected with the server since using the URL that Intellij gave me does not work?

Comment: both server and client has to be connected to same network

Comment: Show the url you use in a browser on your pc to connect with the php file serverd by your webserver. SO test your php files on your pc to start.

Comment: @greenapps So I test my php file directly from Intellij or do I move it into the www folder in Wamp?

Comment: `trying to make an Android app connect to a database` No. You are trying to make an Android app that connects to a webserver on your pc. The webserver then invokes the php interpreter for the mentioned php file. If the php file connects to a database depends on the php schript. It can connect or not. Your android app has never access to that database so it does not connect to it either.

Comment: `So I test my php file directly from Intellij or do I move it into the www folder in Wamp?` You test your php file with a browser on your pc. The php file should then be in the www folder or how it might be called of the webserver.

Comment: @greenapps If my php file should be in the www folder, this means that it would not be included in the Intellij project of the android app in the first place?

Comment: That i dont know as i do not know that IDE. But why should that php file be included in your app or in your project? Php files belong on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If your major concern is reading from the database from an android device, then the URL for an Emulator on the same device as your localhost is `http://10.0.2.2:3306/stickyrice`

If you want to read the database from an actual device, then, you should connect your phone and localhost machine to the same local network, you can do this by sharing a hotspot and turning off your mobile data connection, after that you can obtain your localhost's IP address on the network and your URL become `http://your_localhost_ip_address:3306/stickyrice`

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've tried the first URL on the Emulator, and it says that the page is not working. What I am trying to do is to connect an Android app to a database. But I have problems testing my php to make sure it works on the server. I do not know where to save my php file, since I am using Wamp to run the server, but I am saving it into an Intellij project.

Comment: `and it says that the page is not working.` You url should end with a php filename. `http://............../mypage.php`. And do not use port 3306 as that is the one of the database. For a php schript the default port 80 is used.